# Check CPU utilisation of command in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, word-embedding

Im trying to apply infersent embed-dings on 400k records and the kernel dies every-time i run. i wanted to understand the CPU utilisation, but not able to find any commands which can do it in Jupyter notebook

Answer (score -1):

400k records are too many, maybe your machine does not support them, you can check the processes in:

Mac: Activity Monitor

Windows: Task Manager

Linux: htop in terminal

A way to fix it is create a sample and run the process or run it on a more powerfull server.